# Knockout if statement checking value of function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my app I have several screens that could appear due to a status, available, closed, ext. To make the different parts of the screens appear I was looking at using knockout if statements since the views and such all share the same values and such and it seems a waste to create that many files.

However in my research I could only find knockout if statement that looks like this

```
<!-- if: Availabilty() -->
    <p>this appears</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And this will check if there are variables there and appear, but I can't seem to make it so it will check to see just what the variable that comes back is.

I have tried something like this

```
<!-- if: Availabilty === 'Available' -->
```

or

```
<!-- if: Availabilty() === 'Available' -->
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Try <!-- if: Availabilty == 'Available' -->

Comment: @dotnetstep I have tried that, it breaks my page. I actually have this as something I have already tried in my question

Comment: I dont know if it is a typo in the question but the documentation has the if statement like this: <!-- ko if: something --> they also say that if is a reserved word and in some browsers you need to escape it by doing this: <!-- ko 'if': something -->

Comment: @segFault Yeah, I'm 90% positive you need the ()'s in there because it is an observable. I don't believe if is a reserved word in the html, but I'll give that a try

Comment: @daniel answer was right it will work  . but be careful when using this container-less conditions i.e  mismatch of closing tags is common one in most cases i.e browser unable to read it correctly even for naked eye though everything seems perfect .

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the two letters `ko`: `<!-- ko if: Availabilty() === 'Available' -->`. Since I assume that `Availabilty` is an observable, the brackets are necessary to get its value.

Comment: ...I had this posted above as something I have tried...It does not work

Comment: @zazvorniki I think you're missing the crux of Daniel's answer that you need to add the `ko` to your if statement.

Comment: @zazvorniki Daniel's answer (adding the missing `ko`) seems to work as you have asked [http://jsfiddle.net/dvrxgy8b/](http://jsfiddle.net/dvrxgy8b/)